# Flutter app crashes in release mode when initializing FlutterFFmpegConfig();

Tags: ios, flutter, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

The app is working on Android on Debug mode(only) with no errors in the logcat/terminal.
But when I tested it on iOS (even in debug mode), it crashes on a specific page.
After long tests, I could know that this line was causing the app to crash.

```
FlutterFFmpegConfig _flutterFFmpegConfig = FlutterFFmpegConfig();
```

If I comment that line, the app won't crash, but I need that line to manipulate videos in the app.

I'm using `flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.3.0` in `pubspec.yaml`, and `full-gpl` package is set in `android\build.gradle`

```
ext {
    flutterFFmpegPackage  = "full-gpl"
}
```

Related package initializations code snippet:

```
final FlutterFFmpegConfig _flutterFFmpegConfig = new FlutterFFmpegConfig();
final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
final FlutterFFprobe _flutterFFprobe = new FlutterFFprobe();
```

I'm not sure, but it seems like the app can't handle creating all these objects at the same class!
Anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: can you post some logs from Xcode onto this thread?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try using

```
flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.2.10
```

. That worked for me.